# sort array by multiple keys with optional key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

The following array contains a sample of data from a larger data set -

```
$data =
[
        [
                'readingSequence' => '35',
                'bookID' => '19',
                'chapter' => '130'
        ],
        [
                'readingSequence' => '19',
                'bookID' => '19',
                'chapter' => '27'
        ],
        [
                'readingSequence' => '59',
                'bookID' => '19',
                'chapter' => '133'
        ],
        [
                'readingSequence' => '35',
                'bookID' => '19',
                'chapter' => '129'
        ],
        [
                'readingSequence' => '98',
                'bookID' => '75',
                'chapter' => '6',
                'verses' => '11-20,',
                'versesFirst' => '11'
        ],
        [
                'readingSequence' => '99',
                'bookID' => '75',
                'chapter' => '6',
                'verses' => '1-10',
                'versesFirst' => '1'
        ]
];
```

The use case requires that the elements of `$data` be sorted by `bookID`, then `chapter`, then `versesFirst` if that key exists.

The following code successfully sorts the array by `bookID` and `chapter` but I haven't figured out a way to also sort by `versesFirst` because it is present in some elements but not in others -

```
array_multisort(array_column($data, 'bookID'), SORT_ASC, array_column($data, 'chapter'), SORT_ASC, $data);
```

Here is the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [readingSequence] => 19
            [bookID] => 19
            [chapter] => 27
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [readingSequence] => 35
            [bookID] => 19
            [chapter] => 129
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [readingSequence] => 35
            [bookID] => 19
            [chapter] => 130
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [readingSequence] => 59
            [bookID] => 19
            [chapter] => 133
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [readingSequence] => 98
            [bookID] => 75
            [chapter] => 6
            [verses] => 11-20,
            [versesFirst] => 11
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [readingSequence] => 99
            [bookID] => 75
            [chapter] => 6
            [verses] => 1-10
            [versesFirst] => 1
        )

)
```

Elements 0 to 3 are sorted correctly but elements 4 and 5 are not because `versesFirst` is not included.  When an attempt was made to include it this warning was displayed and the results looked the same as shown above.

> Warning: array_multisort(): Array sizes are inconsistent in C:\development\scratchpad.php on line 122

I could add `[versesFirst] => ''` to the elements that don't have the `versesFirst` key so that it could be included in the multisort but I'd rather not resort to that.  Is there a way to include optional keys in the multisort?  Or is there a different approach entirely to achieve the desired result set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `usort` to accomplish this with `isset` checks for `versesFirst` key.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

usort($data, function($a,$b){
    $book_id_1 = intval($a['bookID']);
    $book_id_2 = intval($b['bookID']);
    
    if($book_id_1 != $book_id_2) return $book_id_1 <=> $book_id_2;
    
    $chapter_1 = intval($a['chapter']);
    $chapter_2 = intval($b['chapter']);
    
    if($chapter_1 != $chapter_2) return $chapter_1 <=> $chapter_2;
    
    if(!isset($b['versesFirst'])){
        return -1;
    }
    
    if(!isset($a['versesFirst'])){
        return 1;
    }
    
    return intval($a['versesFirst']) <=> intval($b['versesFirst']);
});

print_r($data);
```